# PostgreSQL time dynamic stamp query

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL query to get dynamically from yesterday to today. 
Suppose `'2018-08-01 12:00:00'` till `'2018-08-02 08:00:00`'. 
The query should run every day without entering 
today's timestamp and yesterday's timestamp.

Comment: You should clarify your question with a code example. What have you tried and what is your purpose?

Comment: Time tamp should also be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
SELECT whatever_you_need 
FROM your_table 
WHERE stamp BETWEEN now() - INTERVAL '1 DAY' AND now()
```